# Incrementing database value in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Rails, I'd like to update some database value by incrementing it.
Say, I have value 30 in a table and I'd like to add 0.5.

Here is how I've tried to accomplish it:

```
Record.where(:status => "somestatus").first.value.to_f += 0.5
```

RoR complains saying "undefined method `to_f='".
I know that I can obtain value first, calculate the result and update_attributes at the end. But what is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Are you sure you really need floating point numbers in the database? If you need to store fractional parts, consider just multiplying the entire value by 10 or 100 when storing it (e.g. store 3050 instead of 30.5).

Comment: what is the column type? decimal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope the field **value** is of type Float, the following will do the update the value by what ever you want.

```
object = Record.where(:status => "somestatus").first
object.increment!(:value, 0.5)
```

[Check here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment!) for documentation on **increment!** method.

Comment: Thank you, Sagar Bommidi! That helps a lot!